# Error finding e.target using jQuery event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I use jQuery event delegation to get a click event on this markup(el contains multiple `checkboxContainer`s,which is why I would like to delegate the event on `.checkboxContainer` to the parent `el`.The click can happen on `.checkboxContainer` or any of it's `children`):

```
  <div class="checkboxContainer" id="equi-select">
     <span role="checkbox" class="checkboxSpan ">
        <div class="blankDiv" style="display: block;">
           <img class="blankImg" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png">
        </div>
       </span>
       <label class="checkboxLabel">Equipment</label>
  </div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
 el.on("click",".checkboxContainer",function(e){
    var $parent;
    if($(e.target).hasClass(".checkboxContainer"))
        $parent=$(e.target);
    else
        $parent=$(e.target).parents(".checkboxContainer").eq(0);
    var res=$parent.attr("id");
    var objtype=res.substring(0,4);//error here
    var $blankDiv=$parent.find(".blankDiv");
    console.log($blankDiv.css("display"));
    if($blankDiv.css("display")==="none")
    {
        console.log(objtype);
        $blankDiv.css("display","block");
        //make ajax requests to get data from server
     }
     else
        $blankDiv.css("display","block");
 });
```

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
```

How can I improve the targeting of my events?

Comment: You know that instead of `e.target` and then check class / parents class, you can use `this` which will be the element?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon el contains multiple `checkboxContainer`s,which is why I would like to delegate the event on `.checkboxContainer` to the parent `el`.The click can happen on `.checkboxContainer` or any of it's children.

Comment: That was not my point. I meant that you can do `var $parent = $(this);` and skip the following `if...else...`!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks,my code is much simpler now and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Add the toString() method to the line becomming

```
var res=$parent.attr("id").toString();
```